# FMDB Infinite loop due to sqlite3_step and while (retry)

Tags: ios, fmdb

I have a FMDB executeUpdate which cause an infinite loop :

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[CDDBManager getDatabasePath]];

[db closeOpenResultSets];
[db close];
NSLog(@"successfully pass closes");
[db open];
NSLog(@"successfully pass open");
[db setTraceExecution:YES];
BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Player (id, ..., is_user) VALUES (?, ..., ?)",
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.player_id],
                ...
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

NSLog(@"end update");
[db close];
```

I call this method in two different VCs and in one it perfectly work ... in other I have an infinite loop (I print retry in the "do{} while()" of FMDB), so I don't see "end update" ...
As you see, I already try to close all result sets and and the db ...

Anyone can see where I've failed ?

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As a starter, I would check the result of the FMDB open call, it returns false if the open failed.  Also, are both db calls on the same thread?

Comment: A backtrace of all the threads would help out a ton- the database is probably locked in another thread (or even process).

Comment: Ok, I've tried to get the return of open, the database was opened correctly ...
How Can I have a backtrace ?
All my thread are finished normally when I do the request :/

Comment: it's not SQLITE_LOCK but it's SQLITE_BUSY, I don't understand how my database can be busy .. The precedent work is finished ...

Comment: Anyone have the same issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but it is a simple error in function where I close the **FMResultSet** after a return in condition clause ...

Answer (score 1):

I think we had the same problem. I was opening a connection for every method where I wanted to call my database. I fixed it by just opening the connection on init.

Comment: Hum hum, and before that, you closed every time ? Because, it was the same to open/close every time :/

Comment: Yeah, I was opening and closing every time.

Comment: Thank for your response, I gonna to switch branch and test your solution.
Which "init" you talk about ? The view controller for example ?

Comment: I'm just using the initialize block that gets called when the class is first called.

Comment: Nothing to do ... the issue persist ...
- Database busy
- Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (5: database is locked)
- DB Query: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Team(id, name, tag, emblem, back_color, bord_color, desc, powerpoint, ts) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)